# The meaning of as + adj + as + noun + to be?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, conjunctions

> **As serious as the problem was**, no one paid enough attention to
> it.

I want the above sentence to mean: although the problem was very serious, no one paid enough attention to it.

Does the structure “as + adjective + as + noun + to be” like in the above sentence has that meaning?

Comment: Yes, it does.  ,,,

Comment: @Greybeard Can you mention a source?

Comment: See my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Dictionaries do not record this use of ***as... as***. They only stop at the comparison structures with adjectives or adverbs, which is the trap into which the other answer fell.

A way to "go around it" is to look at set phrases that correspond to the use of the OP.

> Definition of ***as much as*** (Entry 2 of 2) 
> : ***even though : despite the fact that***
>
> - ***As much as I*** respect him, I still have to disagree with him on this point. ([M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/as%20much%20as))

I know *much* is an adverb here, but *as* can be followed by [*adjectives OR adverbs*](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/as-as) for similar purposes, so we can replace *much* with an adjective such as *serious*.

---

HOWEVER, your structure is more commonly used without the first AS (which [M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/as) records as an adverb in this particular use), and this is why it was so difficult to find it in the dictionaries. In your sentence,

> *Serious **as** the problem* was, no one paid enough attention to it.

*as* is a conjunction of concession. And if you look up *conjunction "as"*, you will find plenty of dictionary entries explaining it. For example:

> used to say that although something is true, what follows is also true
> SYNONYM though
>
> - *Happy **as** they were*, there was something missing. ([OxfordL](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/as_3#:%7E:text=As%20is%20a%20conjunction%20and,of%20music%2C%20as%20I%20do.))

OR

> used after an adjective or adverb to mean that something is true despite what you are saying
>
> - *Strange **as** it may seem*, I never really wanted to be rich. ([Macmillan](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/as_1))

So your expression is correct, even with the first AS present. I presume the more common construction simply omits it. To avoid the confusion with the comparative meaning? For elegance of style? Who knows...

Comment: The OED does record this use...

Comment: I would be surprised if it didn't. Thing is, most of us have no access to it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it does.

OED:
**As** (conjunction)

> **B4. In parenthetical clauses forming an extension of the subject or predicate, with a somewhat concessive force: *though, however, to whatever degree or extent.***

> **b. With antecedent as.**
>
> 1890   Boston Med. & Surg. Jrnl. 2 Oct. 318/1   *As satisfactory as this operation is.*
>
> 1913   Atlantic Monthly Aug. 231/1   *But as quick as I was, I wasn't quick enough.*
>
> 1985   V. C. Andrews Heaven vii. 133   *As mean as he was, he'd save us from starvation.*
>
> 2008   Independent 5 Nov. 34/4   *As poor as they are, the fashion sense here blows my mind.*

Answer (score -2):

Yes it does.

https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/grammar/british-grammar/as-as

Example sentence in the page

> Greg makes as much money as Mick but not as much as Neil.

Edit: Another example is

> Can you come as soon as possible?

As ___ as can be used to express not only comparisons, but also weightier, mightier meaning by itself.

In the OP example this had been the case, use of "to be" does not affect its usage. Also the attendant clause do not modify the meaning of the clause. that uses "as__as" simile. They can be considered as independent clauses.

Comment: That's not the meaning used in the OP.

Comment: As much money as Mick makes, it's nothing compared to Neil's salary.

Comment: This answer is using a definition that means that two things are equal. How does that apply to the sense in the question?

Comment: Unfortunately, none of the grammar web sites seem to mention the OP's use, as it's less common than the "equality" sense.

Comment: @Barmar. The second example sentence in my answer does not mean "two things are equal".

Comment: It's similar to "Can you come at the same time as possible" -- the time you come and the time it's possible are equal. But it's still not at all like the sense in the question.