# What's the meaning of "as + adj + as st goes"?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, conjunctions

I saw this from an email in my company. The structure seems so strange to me:

> As fundamental and important as (something) goes, we’re
> thrilled to announce...

Having carried out a preliminary research, I saw an almost identical question on this forum [The meaning of as + adj + as + noun + to be?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/597655/the-meaning-of-as-adj-as-noun-to-be). However, it just mentioned the meaning of "as adj as noun to be".

Comment: I don't think it's a standard construction, but it seems to mean the same as "as X as Y is..."

Comment: So is it correct?

Comment: I've never seen it before. There's "as far as X goes...". They were probably confusing the two constructions.

Comment: Thanks @Barmar for your input!

Comment: I tried searching for "as important as X goes". The only examples I could find were "X is as important as what goes on..."

Comment: Yeah, I see @Barmar.

Comment: The full example would be welcome.  This smacks of a misuse of the concessive "_as …as_"  in such (unfrequent) examples as "_As widespread as the effects may be,_, the Midwest will still bear the brunt of the recession.". ("_Even though_ the effects may be widespread")  // (The evidence of a concession would be totally missing and the interpretation should probably be something like "In the light of  (something) being fundamental  and in the light of its importance, we are thrilled…".)